# Find a function $b$ such that the operator $\frac{d}{dx}+b(x)$ is symmetric with the weight $x^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, hilbert-calculus

Find the value of $b(x) \in \mathbb{C}, x\in \mathbb{R}$, so that  $$Â=(Â^{*})^{t}$$ with
$$Â=i\frac{d}{dx}+b(x)$$

Here, $(f|g)$ is defined by
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2}f^{*}(x)g(x)dx
$$

I have found $Im{b(x)}=\dfrac{1}{x} $, is it correct?

Comment: Do $f,g$ vanish quickly as $|x| \to \infty$?

Comment: @copper.hat this is the only information i have. I suppose $$f,g \in L^{2}_{-\infty, infty}$$

Comment: There must be more conditions, just being in $L^2$ doesn't mean differentiable?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, it means differentiable and $$int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f|^{2}dx \in \mathbb{C}$$

Comment: Working formally, I get something like $\operatorname{im} (b(x)) = {1 \over x}$.

Comment: (But it is quite feasible I made a computational mistake!)

Comment: @copper.hat I found that $$Im(b(x))=\frac{i}{x}$$, i will revise my operations. Thank you very much! ;)

Comment: (Note that I am working formally; I used integration by parts and needed to assume something like $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} x^2 \bar{f}(x)g(x) = 0$.)

Comment: @copper.hat yes. I did the same, starting with $$(f|Âf)=(Âf|f)$$. I have to revise my operations. Thank you.